# C reverse two words in a single string in a void function

Tags: c, string, reverse

My function should reverse two strings - first name and surname. So output of John Smith should be Smith John. The problem is, it should be void function. So I guess that global array should be modified. I was trying to code it - I append code, but it doesn't work. My array stays unmodified. I think somewhere in conclusion is error, I am trying to overwrite initial array 'name' in conclusion, it doesn't work. Any idea about mistake please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void reverse(char *name) {
    int index = 0;
    char first[20];
    char second[20];
    bool firstName = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
        if (name[i] == ' ') {
            firstName = false;
            first[i] = '\0';
        }
        else if (firstName)
            first[i] = name[i];
        else {
            second[index] = name[i];
            index++;
        }
    }
    second[index] = ' ';
    second[index+1] = '\0';
    name = strcat(second, first);
}

int main() {
    char name[] = "John Smith";
    printf("originally: %s\n", name);
    reverse(name);
    printf("reversed: %s\n", name);
}
```

Comment: The problem is in `name = strcat(second, first);`. Read the description of `strcat`. And, of course, you cannot copy a string using `=`; you must use `strcpy`. Note that `strcat` needs a large enough buffer for the first argument, and I doubt it is.

Comment: Use `sprintf(name,"%s%s",second,first);`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things it is missing the statement: `#include <stebool.h>`  for the definitions of `bool`, etc

Comment: Regarding: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)`  this statement does not cleanly compile, because it is comparing a 'signed int' with a 'unsigned int'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you do wrong? You fail to return the modified string. Replace `name = strcat(second, first);` with:

```
strcpy(name, second);
strcat(name, first);
```

Here is a very simple alternate solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char *buf) {
    char first[20], last[20];
    if (sscanf(buf, "%19s%19s", first, last) == 2) {
        sprintf(buf, "%s %s", last, first);
    }
}

int main() {
    char name[] = "John Smith";
    printf("originally: %s\n", name);
    reverse(name);
    printf("reversed: %s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Monc: my mistake. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea about mistake please?

In main function we passed *name* to reverse() here *name* contains address of array name[] say P1 for example.

```
reverse(name); // name is P1
```

In function reverse *name* will contain address of array *name* i.e. P1

```
void reverse(char *name) { // name still p1
```

and this name is local to function.

Here, let us try to understand strcat first.
As man pages suggests:

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
The strcat() function return a pointer to the resulting string dest.
```

As in below code we are updating *name*. Now name will contain pointer to destination string say p2 for example.

```
name = strcat(second, first); // name has become p2
```

Now when we return to main(), *name* still contains the address of array i.e P1 (function context is finished so does it local variables) not the address of final string i.e P2.

```
reverse(name); // name is p1
printf("reversed: %s\n", name); // name is p1
```

Answer (score 0):

Intermediate buffers are boring. Here's a char-by-char swapper with no size limit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void reverse(char *name) {
    char c1, c2;
    size_t pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos_sep, name_len, count;

    {
        char *p_sep = strchr(name, ' ');

        if (!p_sep) {
            return;
        }
        pos_sep = p_sep - name;
        name_len = pos_sep + strlen(p_sep);
    }

    c1 = name[0];
    for (count = name_len; count != 0; count--) {
        {
            if (pos2 < pos_sep)  {
                pos2 = pos2 + name_len - pos_sep;
            } else if (pos2 > pos_sep) {
                pos2 = pos2 - (pos_sep + 1);
            } else {
                pos2 = name_len - (pos_sep + 1);
            }
            c2 = name[pos2];
            name[pos2] = c1;
            c1 = c2;
            if (pos2 == pos1) {
                pos1++;
                pos2 = pos1;
                c1 = name[pos1];
            }
        }
        //fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", name);
    }
}

static void _test(char *name, const char *expected) {
    reverse(name);
    if (0 != strcmp(expected, name)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "something wrong\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

#define test(name, expected) do { \
    static char buf[] = name; \
    _test(buf, expected); \
} while(0)

int main()
{

    test("abc", "abc");

    test("abcde 123", "123 abcde");
    test("abc 12345", "12345 abc");

    test("ab 12", "12 ab");
    test("a 12", "12 a");
    test("ab 1", "1 ab");
    test("a ", " a");
    test(" 1", "1 ");
    test(" ", " ");
    test("ab 123", "123 ab");
    test("ab  12", " 12 ab");
    test("abc 1234", "1234 abc");

    test("abc 12345", "12345 abc");
    test("abcd 1234", "1234 abcd");
    test("abcd 12345", "12345 abcd");

    fprintf(stderr, "all fine\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. eliminates unnecessary local variables
3. makes use of the Variable Length Array feature of C
4. performs the desired operation.

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// prototypes
void reverse(char *name);

int main( void )
{
    char name[] = "John Smith";
    printf("originally: %s\n", name);
    reverse(name);
    printf("reversed: %s\n", name);
}


void reverse(char *name)
{
    char genFirst[ strlen( name )+1 ];
    char genSecond[ strlen( name )+1 ];

    memset( genFirst,  '\0', strlen( name ) );
    memset( genSecond, '\0', strlen( name ) );

    size_t i;
    for ( i = 0; name[i] && name[i] != ' '; i++ )
    {
        genFirst[i] = name[i];
    }

    i++;

    for ( size_t j = 0; name[j]; j++ )
    {
        genSecond[ j ] = name[ i+j ];
    }

    genSecond[i] = ' ';

    strcpy( name, genSecond );
    strcat( name, genFirst );
}
```

the resulting output is:

```
originally: John Smith
reversed: Smith John
```